# Suggest different version for this configuration because Ubuntu 12.04 taking too long to bootup & performing real slow

Tags: 12.04

I have 768MB ram and 1.7GHz Intel processor.

I think that's the problem . So please recommend me a lighter version of Ubuntu. That will give me optimum performance. Because i have seen it performing really well even on lower configuration systems.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Ubuntu that has the least impact on resources is [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/). It uses the LXDE desktop environment. Some people will tell you that Xubuntu is better, but there are things available that prove that it actually uses more RAM than a stock Ubuntu install.

It's a bit easier to just do a fresh install of Lubuntu than to try to convert a current installation of Ubuntu to Lubuntu (though it is possible). If you absolutely want to do the conversion I can provide you the information on how to do it.